# Identify HE-AAC audio on Android for proper decoding and playback

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, aac, mediaextractor

I use the `MediaExtractor / MediaCodec` combo on Android (target API level >= 16) to decode audio streams. Now I have a subtle problem when playing back mp4/m4a containers that contain MPEG-4 HE-AAC audio data.

When querying track's `MediaFormat` for the `MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE` I actually get only half of the expected size, e.g for a track that needs a playback sample rate of 44100 the `MediaFormat` returns 22050. After reading some documentation on HE-AAC I understand that this is "correct" in terms of how that codec works.

Still, to play back the audio track on an `AudioTrack` instance I have to configure it with the correct (playback) samplerate which is 44100 and not 22050.

Therefore, I am looking for a way to know for sure when the audio is HE-AAC encoded with API target level >= 16 so I can set the sample rate of the `AudioTrack` to two times the reported sample rate.

**Edit:** I do check the `MediaFormat` when `MediaCodec` return with `MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED`. The format will look like this:

```
max-input-size=946, 
aac-profile=2, 
mime=audio/mp4a-latm, 
durationUs=158499410,
csd-0=java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer[position=0,limit=5,capacity=5], 
channel-count=2, 
sample-rate=22050
```

To get a proper playback on the `AudioTrack` I need to set the sample rate to 2 * sample-rate = 44100.

I wonder if the `csd-0` contains more information to deduce the profile/format/etc. For the above example the 5 bytes from the `csd-0` buffer looks like this:

```
0x13 0xffffff90 0x56 0xffffffe5 0xffffffa0
```

Now I'm wondering about the concrete structure of this "codec specific data"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only treat the `MediaFormat` returned by `MediaExtractor` as a hint; you need to look at what `MediaCodec` returns with `INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED`, this should return the real samplerate. This means that you can only configure `AudioTrack` once decoding of the content has started.

Comment: I already do this. Actually, the format looks like this when `INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED`is triggered: `{max-input-size=946, aac-profile=2, mime=audio/mp4a-latm, durationUs=158499410, csd-0=java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer[position=0,limit=5,capacity=5], channel-count=2, sample-rate=22050}` but still the real sample rate I have to set on the `AudioTrack` is 44100

Comment: That sounds pretty bad then - which decoder (`MediaCodec.getName()`) is this, and on what device? If you use `OMX.google.aac.decoder` (which you can find via `MediaCodecList`) I would guess that you'd get the right sample rate (although I haven't verified it).

Comment: it's indeed the `OMX.google.aac.decoder` that is being used. Device is Moto G 2nd Gen but the same happens on S4 Mini.

Comment: nevermind - the `MediaFormat` retrieved from the `MediaCodec` after it signals `INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED` is the right one to configure the playback. I was still looking at the initial format which of course does not update...

Answer (score 0):

You need resample the audio buffer. there is a lib for it.
https://github.com/google/oboe